# maximum capacity for windows message queue on windows server 2008

Tags: windows, message-queue

I have a production environment that deals with a firehose stream of data for multiple data sources. Currently I parse the data in realtime with the data being queued in windows message queues. I read somewhere that the max number in any given queue is 10000. My concern is that I am will be increasing the number of streams  x 10 with the amount of data increasing x 100. Of course my processing needs to be able to scale and I am not sure if this current setup will be viable.

My current machines and development environment:

Visual studio 2010
Sql server 2008 R2
Windows 2008 RS standard
Dell PowerEdge R-610
Dual Quad Core Xeon Processors 
4x300GB HDD 2.5"
Intel() Xeon(R) CPU E5649 @ 2.53 GHZ (dual processors)
32 GB RAM
64 bit- OS

What is maximum number of queues I can actually have if max posts per queue is 10000?
Would it be more viable to use more machines or can these be modified to accomodate the new influx of data?
I currently asynchrously write each message/post to txt files to store a period of time, so this needs to be taken into account as well.

```
Imports System.Messaging

 ...
   Dim q As MessageQueue
    If MessageQueue.Exists(".\private$\TwitterQueue") Then
        q = New MessageQueue(".\private$\TwitterQueue")
    End If

     message = q.Peek(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20.0))
```

This is the windows message queue service. Will have to read up on the other types.

Comment: Please be more specific which types of message queues you are using. Are you using [window manager message queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms632590) or [network message queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms711472) or [point-to-point message queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa909023)?

Answer (score 3):

The 10,000 message limit applies to window manager message queues. But you are not using those. You're using network message queues. So the information you "read somewhere" does not apply to your case.

Comment: I don't know. I was saying that the 10,000 message limit does not apply here.